# Why will crushing a water bottles keep the water in fizzy condition?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, everyday-life, water

Everybody is talking only about CO<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! When you ask a question, please try to make it accessible to readers who may not immediately know what you are talking about. In particular, please don't only put the question in the title, but repeat it in the body. Who is this "everybody" you mention, why are they "talking only about CO$_{2}$", and what has this to do with your question? The more specific you are and the more context you give, the better answerers will be able to give precisely the answer you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. I believe you are referring to crushing soda bottles to maintain its fizziness.

I'm going to need to talk about CO<sub>2</sub>, because I can't explain it without that. Soda is fizzy because of dissolved CO<sub>2</sub>, kind of like how sugar is dissolved in lemonade. Basically, when you open a soda bottle, drink some of the soda, and leave out some space, the dissolved CO<sub>2</sub> escapes. By leaving more room in the bottle for the CO<sub>2</sub> to escape into, you are allowing CO<sub>2</sub> to leave the liquid soda. By crushing the bottle, you leave less space for the CO<sub>2</sub> to escape into, so the CO<sub>2</sub> stays in the liquid soda.